# How to disable portage LICENSE checks

Tags: gentoo, licenses, emerge

Whenever I install a package with an EULA, portage asks me to add it to `package.license`:

```
The following license changes are necessary to proceed:
 (see "package.license" in the portage(5) man page for more details)
#required by chrome-binary-plugins (argument)
>=www-plugins/chrome-binary-plugins-9999 google-chrome
#required by google-chrome (argument)
>=www-client/google-chrome-26.0.1410.40_beta189199:beta google-chrome
```

Since I don't read the licence anyway and portage isn't even asking me to do so, I'd like to globally disable this check. How to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Which licenses portage accepts is governed by the `ACCEPT_LICENSE` variable in `make.conf`. This variable is the counterpart to `package.license` the same way `USE` is to `package.use`, `ACCEPT_KEYWORDS` to `package.keywords`, etc.. By default, this variable is set to `@FREE`, which means "only accept all licenses in the `FREE` set". This set contains all licenses that require the user to accept them. In order to be able to install all packages without additional license-related prompts, just add the following line to `/etc/portage/make.conf`:

```
ACCEPT_LICENSE="*"
```

Conversely, you could also block out all non-free packages with `ACCEPT_LICENSE="@FREE"`, or choose any other combination of licenses you like. See `/usr/portage/profiles/license_groups` for details

Comment: +1 for the `ACCEPT_LICENSE="@FREE"` hint :)

Comment: small typo in directory `/usr/portage/profiles` (profiles should be plural). Great answer!

Comment: Note that `@FREE` is the default now